# How does the Combat Medic Perk in Fallout 4 work?

Tags: fallout-4

Does anyone have the Combat medic perk in Fallout 4? It's supposed to heal 100 HP if the players health is less than 10%. But how does it work? Does it have some inner cooldown, and if so how long is the cooldown? Is it something you have to use, or is it automatically activated? Does it heal over time, or is it instant?

It takes a while to get the companion perks, so I'd rather know what it actually does before I invest the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As per this Fallout 4 Perks Comparison Guide](http://www.gameranx.com/features/id/31579/article/fallout-4-companions-the-complete-list/):

> Combat Medic (heal 100 points if health falls below 10%; can only be used once each day)

This says to me that in the instance your health drops below 10% then you will gain 100 hit points up to a maximum of one time per day.

Comment: This happens automatically with no input from the user? Have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, as tooltip says, health should restore as soon as your health drops below 10%. However, it seems that this doesn't work, at least I can't get 100hp heal from falling damage. Probably, perk is bugged right now.

Comment: This does not add any relevant information that the accepted answer does not already state in greater detail. Please keep in mind that duplicate answers are frowned upon here and may be subject to deletion.